# Collection count is not working for current view linklists

Tags: collections, shopify

Use of "collection.products_count" to show the number of the total product of the collection.

collection.products_count is not working for the current filter view (tagged view) when try with linklists or specific collection.
e.g

```
{% for link in linklists.filter-collection.links %}
   {{ link.title }} // collection title
   {{ link.object.products_count }} //collection product count 
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
collections["pro-athlete-meal-box"].products_count
```

it's not working on both way. All time it's returning all product count instead of the current filter view.

here is official document https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/collection

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way:
(One thing the links of the link-list should be assigned to collections)

{% for link in linklists.filter-collection.links %}

After for-loop add this following code and check output.

```
{% assign coll_handle = link.url | split: "collections/" | last %}
{%- assign current_collection = collections[coll_handle] -%}

{{ childlink.title | escape }}

{{ current_collection.all_products_count }}
```

OR Only :

```
{{ collection.all_products_count }}
```

Comment: I know that but I don't need all collection count I need count base on current filter view
"need  the count of all products in a collection for the current view. For example, if a collection is filtered by tag,"

Comment: Okay, Can you please confirm your result is load with Ajax or after reload page?

Comment: I'm not using ajax for that